# ngRepeat in ui router

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-router

i have a dynamic form that is generated from a json

and my ngRepeat looks like this:

```
                <div ng-repeat="(q, w) in user.education">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="{{q}}">{{q}}</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="{{q}}"  ng-model="user.education.{{q}}">
                        </div>


                </div>
```

so the problem is that the {{q}} in the ng-model isnt showing the data... but in the label and input name it is working...any ideas why? because i will need to continue using these variables..i know that the brackets are not neccesary because of the ng. but whenb i loose the brackets...then the 'q' character is shown..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can just change this:

```
ng-model="user.education.{{q}}"
```

to this:

```
ng-model="user.education[q]"
```

So referencing your variable `q` property in the user.education object via bracket notation rather than dot notation.